# How to compare coefficients of variation for lognormal data?

Tags: statistical-significance, lognormal-distribution, coefficient-of-variation, variability, geometric-mean

I want to compare the variability of two log-normal samples. They are being summarized as [Coefficient of variations (CVs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_coefficient_of_variation) and I want to test if one sample's CV is different from the other's.

To compare the geometric means, I performed a t-test on log-transformed data, then applied the antilog to go back to the original scale of the problem.

1. In the same logic, is it appropriate to apply the F-test for variances on log-transformed data and then revert to the antilog scale?
2. If not, is there a significance test for CVs or geometric CVs?

Comment: Maybe you should mention that CV here is coefficient of variation and not cross validation.

Comment: @MichaelChernick thanks, edited in first occurance and title